# How to run .ts file script and angular 5 build using NPM

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ts-node

I have a file with .ts extension and I want to execute this file first and then to run npm run build to build my angular 5 project

```
package.json
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "compile": "npm-run-all myts build",
    "myts": "ts-node git.version.ts",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
  },
```

And I get this error

> npm run compile

```
> ng-forms-api@0.0.0 compile C:\Users\George35mk\Documents\Projects\gui\frontend\> 
npm-run-all myts build

'npm-run-all' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ng-forms-api@0.0.0 compile: `npm-run-all myts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-forms-api@0.0.0 compile script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\George35mk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-01T14_47_01_179Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\George35mk\Documents\Projects\gui\frontend\
```

### If I run this is work

> ts-node git.version.ts

### The problem is I cant run serial scripts using npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using node/express/angular with typescript and found only one way to do all the work with one command without installing anything.

My way let me:
 1. Compile node ts server files to js and watch for changes in ts files
 2. Compile angular project, serve it to node server and watch for changes in angular
 3. Run node server and restart it if there was changes.

All that i do is run "npm start"

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "start tsc --watch & cd ../angular & start ng build --watch & cd ../node & timeout 15 & start nodemon --watch ../angular/dist --watch dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "ws": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.9.2",
    "@types/ws": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

My project structure:

```
My_project
 - node
 - angular

tsconfig.json optons:
    "outDir": "dist", 
    "rootDir": "src"
```

Comment: Thank you @RTW TMI

Comment: little changes. Added --watch dist and dont forget isntal nodemon globally :)

Answer (score 1):

> Modify the package.json in the following way:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "compile": "npm run myts && npm run build",
  "myts": "ts-node git.version.ts",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
}
```

> Explanation

1. `&&` makes sure that first command runs, followed by the other.
2. You don't need `npm-run-all` to do that
3. But if you want to use `npm-run-all`, then do `npm install npm-run-all --save-dev`

Comment: Thank you I have forget this question.